# How can i add an if else statement to this SQL trigger that calls a Function

Tags: sql, if-statement, triggers

I have a SQL trigger that calls a function to split the file name from a delimeter. the problem is that the first string determines how to split the data. my question is how can i keep adding to this statement.

```
USE [dw1]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[SplitFileName]    Script Date: 03/02/2015 14:18:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SplitFileName] 
   ON  [dbo].[DOCUMENTS] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @varDWDOCID int, @varFILENAME nvarchar(255), @varDEALER_NUM nvarchar(255), @varINVOICE_NUMBER nvarchar(255), @varWEEK_ENDING nvarchar(255), @varDOCTYPE nvarchar(255)
    Select
      @varDWDOCID = inserted.[DWDOCID],
      @varFILENAME = isnull(inserted.[FILENAME],''),
      @varDEALER_NUM = isnull(inserted.[DEALER_NUM],''),
      @varINVOICE_NUMBER = isnull(inserted.[INVOICE_NUMBER], ''),
      @varWEEK_ENDING = isnull(inserted.[WEEK_ENDING],''),
      @varDOCTYPE = isnull(inserted.[DOCTYPE],'')
      from inserted
-- ============================================= 
-- Author:                            <Name> 
-- Create date: 3/2/2015 
-- Description: Split document based on dash and also calling a function... 
-- ============================================= 

;WITH cte AS
  (  
  SELECT t.dwdocid, t.FILENAME, t.DEALER_NUM, t.INVOICE_NUMBER, t.WEEK_ENDING, t.DOCTYPE, 
         NewDOCTYPE = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 1 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewDEALER_NUMBER = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 2 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewWEEK_ENDING = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 3 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewINVOICE_NUMBER = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 4 THEN o.val END) OVER()
  FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS_CHRIS t CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(t.FILENAME, '-') o where t.DWDOCID=@varDWDOCID and LEFT(FILENAME, 12) ='123InvoiceIn'
  )
Update cte
SET DOCTYPE=NewDOCTYPE,
DEALER_NUM=NewDEALER_NUMBER,
WEEK_ENDING=NewWEEK_ENDING,
INVOICE_NUMBER=NewWEEK_ENDING
FROM inserted
END
/*
;WITH cte AS
 (    
  SELECT r.dwdocid, r.FILENAME, r.DEALER_NUM, r.INVOICE_NUMBER, r.WEEK_ENDING, r.DOCTYPE, 
         NewDOCTYPE = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 1 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewINVOICE_NUMBER = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 2 THEN o.val END) OVER()
         NewDEALER_NUM = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 3 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewWEEK_ENDING = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 3 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS_CHRIS r CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(r.FILENAME, '-') o where t.DWDOCID=@varDWDOCID and LEFT(FILENAME, 13) ='123InvoiceOut'
  )
Update cte
SET DOCTYPE=NewDOCTYPE,
DEALER_NUM=NewDEALER_NUMBER,
WEEK_ENDING=NewWEEK_ENDING,
INVOICE_NUMBER=NewWEEK_ENDING
FROM inserted
END*/
```

How can i add the '123InvoiceOut' in like a If..Else statement so it will execute at the same time?

Comment: A side problem, I think that you are cross-joining your cte with `inserted` in this UPDATE.  That's not a good thing, it will be slow and probably not do what you expect.

Comment: The first part is working fine. it is doing what i want it to do. I need to be able to add the second part which is commented out. the only difference is that i need it to do a different order when the 'FILENAME' is different.

Comment: It's unclear from your description what you actually want to do with an "If..Else" in this SQL code.  There are different statements, functions and operators to allow conditional processing in SQL Server, but they apply to different contexts, so it depends on what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Basically, I need the Trigger to fire only if a condition is met. if ''123InvoiceIn' then do the first update. If''123InvoiceOut' then do the second update and so on i have like 10 more but if i can get the right syntax. i should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: Maybe post example code of what you want to do, and we can tell you what the correct syntax is to do that?

Comment: IF LEFT(FILENAME, 12) ='123InvoiceIn' --> 123InvoiceIn-044632-15021507129 I need to populate doctype with '123InvoiceIn', Dealer_Num with '044632', Week_ending with '15021507129' and Invoice_Num with '15021507129.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT .....  FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get *one arbitrary row* and you'll **ignore all others**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: IF LEFT(FILENAME, 13)='123InvoiceOut' --> 123InvoiceOut-15022238842-47158 I need to populate doctype with '123InvoiceOut', Invoice_Num with 15022238842, Dealer_Num with '47158' and WeekEnding with '15022238842. the order of the fields if different. i already have it working for the first update but i now need to add a second update that calls the same function. i don't know how to format this nices.

Comment: @marc_s the trigger will only run when it meets the IF statement which i so desperately need and only when a new row gets inserted into the table.  you are right, i will remote the UPDATE from the trigger as i only want it to run when something new gets inserted.

Comment: @user2066533: but you have the **same MAJOR flaw** when handling only inserts - what if an `INSERT` statement inserts 10 rows at once??

Comment: That won't happen on my case.

Comment: I have a SQL fiddle here [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bbba8/1/0) Rows 1 to 8 are for 123InvoiceIn and 9-10 for 123InvoiceOut

Comment: Do any of you have any suggestions or at least some samples where of something similar?

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)